# Which ssh-agent to connect to when setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK inside screen/tmux?

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-agent

I am using a variation of the following line:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(find /tmp/ssh-* -name agent.\* -uid $(id -u)|head -n 1)
```

[found over at Github](https://github.com/scharan/Goodies/blob/master/ssh-agent-restore). This way I should be able to use my forwarded agent connection on the remote system even from inside `screen` or `tmux`. However, what if I establish two separate SSH connections to the remote machine and both of them run a separate instance of the `ssh-agent`?

The question boils down to:

1. should I avoid starting another instance of `ssh-agent` in the first place?
2. if the answer is no on the preceding point, how do I choose to which *existing* socket to connect, given there are multiple running at the moment?
3. <s>bonus question: can there be something like a stale socket? I.e. when I look for the socket using the `find` command above, can I end up with two alternatives one of which has gone bad/stale? Or are sockets cleaned up automatically when the process owning them dies?</s> Turns out there can be stale sockets. Just had the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid starting multiple `ssh-agent` processes in the first place. You can use a command like `pgrep -u <your_username> ssh-agent` to detect the PID of your `ssh-agent` process (or lack thereof).